# How can I cat output of a system("pwd") with text in awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Please bear with me as I'm very new to shell scripting and awk. I've been trying to create a playlist to play some of my music in Mplayer, but it only works if the full path to each file is specified. I've been trying to set up a little shell script to insert the output of $pwd before each filename and write it to a playlist, like so:

```
ls | awk '{system("pwd") | getline x; grep -v 0; gsub("\n",""); print x"/"$1}' > playlist.txt
```

(the grep is to get rid of the "0" status output from system("pwd")). However, there is a newline in x, so I get the output

```
/home/(directory)
/Song_1.mp3
/home/(directory)
/Song_2.mp3
```

and what I want is

```
/home/(directory)/Song_1.mp3
/home/(directory)/Song_2.mp3
```

Comment: You shouldn't **ever** use `ls` in a script, unless the sole purpose is to display content to a user. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using awk or anything, but I think this does what you want?

```
find -printf "\"$PWD/%f\"\n"
```

Comment: Why would you use that over `find "$PWD" -print` (which is also more portable, whereas `-printf` is a GNU extension)?

Comment: Because it will handle filenames with spaces quite nicely?

Comment: Not any better than `find "$PWD" -print` will, no.

Comment: ...and woe unto anyone who has a `%` in their directory name.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this topic after so long, but I gave up on it before when I got busy at work, and I just got back to it. This does exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, there are other ways to get the fully-qualified paths requested in the OP.

For those who are using Awk for other purposes and require the working directory, Awk has access to environment variables through the `ENVIRON` array.  You can access it via `ENVIRON["PWD"]`.

The directory is fully qualified, so the requested `/home/(directory)/filename.mp3` may not quite work as expected.  Even so, a one-liner that should work for OP's purpose:

```sh
ls -1 | awk '{ print(ENVIRON["PWD"] "/" $0); }' > playlist.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` like this:

```
printf "%s\n" "$PWD"/*
```

OR else your awk:

```
printf "%s\n" * | awk 'BEGIN{"pwd"|getline d} {print d "/" $0}'
```

Comment: Quotes for the `$PWD` (`"$PWD"/*`), and maybe it could stand to be more strongly recommended as the only good-practices approach given.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps trying to do this?

```
ls -1 ${PWD}/*.mp3
```

or

```
find "${PWD}" -maxdepth 1 -name "*.mp3" -print
```

or

```
for f in ${PWD}/*.mp3
do
  echo "${f}"
done
```

Comment: The `ls -1` approach is bad practice, and should be flagged as such. Also, needs more quotes when expanding `$PWD`.

Comment: ...though `find -print` is *also* bad practice (POSIX filenames can contain newlines, and so can't be safely represented in a newline-separated list), there are, after all, levels of degree.

Comment: Depends on whether it's just creating an output list for human perusal, or for further processing. If the output is intended for further processing, definitely avoid the `ls` approach...

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: `$(pwd)` is unnecessarily inefficient -- why would you spawn a subshell just to get the current directory? `"$PWD"` is a much more efficient way to retrieve that value. Also, needs quotes or it won't work when the current directory name contains whitespace.